# Trying to ID this regulator IC

Tags: voltage-regulator, identification

I'm trying to determine what linear regulator this is. It is on a Hayward Industries power supply, no schematics are available. Not sure of pin configuration. Normal voltages from bottom left if it is pin 1, then 24 V @ pin 1 and 12 V @ pin 3, pin 2 is GND.

[image]

Comment: Assuming 12v is the normal output you could probably replace it with any of dozens of equivalent parts. Linear regulators are fairly generic.

Comment: Before trying to identify the part based on IC code. If this is a SOT23-5 package, then it is typical has pin 1 as Vin, pin 5 as Vout, and Pin is usually some sort of control (enable, shutdown, etc.), so Pin 1 has 24V, and Pin3 has 12V doesn't sound right.

Comment: @hcheung Ive seen them in every pinout combination, so I dont think that is super meaningful